# Multisite, with virtual root

Tags: multisite, network-admin

I have a multisite network with

define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'fruit.shop.com');

So that the "Network Admin" is on fruit.shop.com, but still be able to add sub-domains from the 2nd level domain.

I'd like to use this to create blogs at locations like

apple.shop.com
orange.shop.com
pineapple.shop.com

And shop.com point to some other server entirely.

How do I do this?